# Flutter: Make text part visible when keyboard is open

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm having a problem with the design of my app.

On image 1 you can see the screen, its all inside a scaffold, the white part in the midle is a list inside of a container.
On imagem 2 you can see what happens when i click on the textformfield at the bottom of the screen (which is in a bottomNavigationBar).

So when i click the on the text field the keyboard hides the text part and the user doenst knows what is being typed.
Is there a way to expand the bottom part when i click the textformfield? Or any way to show de typed text in a field over the keyboard when im typing?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Heres the code for the bottombar:

````
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 180.0,
          color: Colors.blue[400],
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Container(
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 70,
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    hint: Text('Choose '),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      print("VALUE DO DROPDOWN $value");
                      funcionarioDrop = value[1];
                      // var funcionarioDrop = value;
                      // here you can pass it to a variable for example
                    },
                    items: newFuncionariosList,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 6.0,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _codprodController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.blue,
                            onPrimary: Colors.white,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text("IR"),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            Response response;
                            Dio dio = new Dio();
                            String url = 'http://192.168.15.2:8090/api/getPeca';
                            response = await dio.post(url,
                                data: {"codprod": _codprodController.text});
                            print(response.statusCode);
                            print(response.data);
                            if (response.data == 'not_found') {
                              BotToast.showText(
                                  text: "Peça não encontrada",
                                  clickClose: true,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                                  align: Alignment(0, 0));
                            } else {
                              produtoDesc =
                                  response.data[0]['Descricao'].toString();
                              produtosList1.add(new ProdutoOs(
                                  cod_produto:
                                      response.data[0]['Codigo'].toString(),
                                  qtd: 24, //int.parse(_qtdPecaController.text),
                                  desc:
                                      response.data[0]['Descricao'].toString(),
                                  numOs: "produtosList1[0].numOs",
                                  codOs: produtosList1[0].codOs,
                                  funcionario: funcionarioDrop,
                                  cliente: "produtosList1[0].cliente",
                                  status: 'produtosList1[0].status'));
                              setState(() {});
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 8.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(produtoDesc == null ? "- - -" : produtoDesc)
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Since the TextField is in the bottom bar, you can use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` inside the Scaffold to avoid the scaffold's floating widgets size.

Your Scaffold should look like,

```
    Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
...);
```

Comment: Does your BottomBar have a Column?, Please add the code for you are using for BottomBar

Comment: Yes, there are 2 columns.

Comment: sorry for the delay, i have added the code for the bottombar

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
Wrap your widget below in a **`SingleChildScrollView`** and that should solve your problem.

```
 SingleChildScrollView (
            child: Container (
           // your widget
           )
    )
```

In addition, this may help you, you can wrap your body in a GestureDetector widget and in the onTap property, add the following:

```
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of (context);
         currentFocus.unfocus ();
```

And this will cause that when you press any part of the screen, the keyboard is hidden.

I leave you an example of how to implement it:

```
body: GestureDetector (
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of (context);
        currentFocus.unfocus ();
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView (
        child: Container (
          padding: EdgeInsets.all (50),
          child: Column (
            children: [
              TextFormField (
                decoration: InputDecoration (
                  hintText: "Example",
                ),

              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: I have add the singlechindscrollview but got errors like "
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#c21ff relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT" and blank screen

Comment: I recently had the same error, and what worked for me was adding `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to the` Column` widget, in the case of being a `ListView` widget, add` shrinkWrap: true`.
Another possible solution could be that all the widgets that are inside the `Column` or` Row`, you wrap them in `Flexible` or` Expanded`.